# How to find the curve extremizing a given functional?

Tags: calculus-of-variations

Given a functional $$I(y)=\int_1^2 {\frac {\sqrt{1+(y'(x))^2}}{x}}dx ,$$ with $y(1)=0$ and $y(2)=1$.

How to find the curve extremizing this functional?

Comment: You've covered the Euler-Lagrange equation, yes?

Comment: Correctly solving the equation for $c$ and $d$ in the answer below, we get $y(x)=2-\sqrt{5-x^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

For the functional
$$
I[y] = \int\limits_a^b L(x, y, y') \, dx
$$
you need to solve the Euler-Lagrange equation
$$
0 
= \frac{\delta I}{\delta y}
= \frac{\partial L}{\partial y} 
-\frac{d}{dx} \frac{\partial L}{\partial y'}
=
- \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{y'}{x\sqrt{1+(y')^2}}\right)
$$
under the given conditions. That means
\begin{align}
c^2 x^2 (1+ (y')^2) &= (y')^2 \iff \\
y' &= \pm \frac{c x}{\sqrt{1-c^2 x^2}} \Rightarrow \\
y
&=  \mp \frac{\sqrt{1-c^2 x^2}}{c} + d
\end{align}
Those are scaled and $y$-translated half circles. Further the two conditions on $y$ should determine the integration constants $c$ and $d$.
\begin{align}
0 &= \mp \frac{\sqrt{1-c^2}}{c} + d \\
1 &= \mp \frac{\sqrt{1-4 c^2}}{c} + d 
\end{align}
This means
$$
d = \pm \frac{\sqrt{1-c^2}}{c}
= 1 \pm \frac{\sqrt{1-4c^2}}{c}
$$
which gives
\begin{align}
1 
&= \pm \left(\frac{\sqrt{1-c^2}}{c} - \frac{\sqrt{1-4c^2}}{c}\right) \\
&= \frac{1-c^2+1-4c^2-2\sqrt{(1-c^2)(1-4c^2)}}{c^2}
\end{align}
and
$$
1-3c^2 = 1-5c^2+4c^4 \iff
1 = 2c^2 \iff
c = \pm 1 / \sqrt{2}
$$
and this means I made an error somewhere, because $d$ would be imaginary.